# Import xlsx file into Python using xlrd

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlsx, xlrd

Trying to import a .xlsx file into Python. I've google and google. I had this code written and working for .csv but it needs to be for .xlsx files. So I basically pieced together and did a hail mary in hopes that it would work. Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

** Added my whole code and a snippet of the data file. I need it to import .xlsx and execute the data.

```
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('GAT_US_PartReview_2017-06-23.xlsx')

worksheet = workbook.get_sheet(0, update_pos=True)

header = []
report_card = []

# Count Stmnts for Required Data
valid_count = 0
app_req_count = 0
intr_req_count = 0
oe_intr_req_count = 0
part_img_req_count = 0
upc_req_count = 0
unspsc_req_count = 0
msds_req_count = 0

# Count Stmts for Missing Data
missing_app_count = 0
missing_intr_count = 0
missing_oe_intr_count = 0
missing_mpcc_count = 0
missing_attr_values_count = 0
missing_part_img_count = 0
missing_upc_count = 0
missing_warr_text_count = 0
missing_warr_pdf_count = 0
missing_unspsc_count = 0
missing_msds_count = 0


for row_num, row in enumerate(worksheet):
    if row_num <= 4:
        #  print(row)  # Print out the header
        header.append([row[0], row[2]])
    else:
        hq_line, part_no, part_class, appl_req, appl_count, intr_req, 
        intr_count, oe_intr_req, has_oe_intr, has_attr_editor, 
        has_attr_values, part_img_req, has_part_img, has_mpcc, warr_req, 
        has_warr_txt, has_warr_pdf, msds_req, has_msds, upc_req, has_upc, 
        has_unspsc, attr_count, attrval_count, valid_part = row

    if valid_part == 'YES':
        valid_count += 1

        # Required Parts Count
        if appl_req == 'YES':
            app_req_count += 1
        if intr_req == 'YES':
            intr_req_count += 1
        if oe_intr_req == 'YES':
            oe_intr_req_count += 1
        if part_img_req == 'YES':
            part_img_req_count += 1
        if upc_req == 'YES':
            upc_req_count += 1
        if msds_req == 'YES':
            msds_req_count += 1

        # Missing Data Counts
        if appl_req == 'YES' and appl_count == '0':
            missing_app_count += 1
        if intr_req == 'YES' and intr_count == '0':
            missing_intr_count += 1
        if oe_intr_req == 'YES' and has_oe_intr == '0':
             missing_oe_intr_count += 1
        if has_mpcc == 'NO':
             missing_mpcc_count += 1
        if has_attr_values == 'NO':
            missing_attr_values_count += 1
        if has_part_img == 'NO':
            missing_part_img_count += 1
        if upc_req == 'YES' and has_upc == '0':
            missing_upc_count += 1
        if warr_req == 'YES' and has_warr_txt == 'NO':
            missing_warr_text_count += 1
        if warr_req == 'YES' and has_warr_pdf == 'NO':
            missing_warr_pdf_count += 1
        if has_unspsc == 'NO':
            missing_unspsc_count += 1
        if msds_req == 'YES' and has_msds == 'NO':
            missing_msds_count += 1

# Statements for Required Counts
valid_parts = ('Number of Valid Parts: ', '{:,}'.format(valid_count))
application_required = ('Application Records Required: ', 
'{:,}'.format(app_req_count))
interchange_required = ('Interchange Records Required: ', 
'{:,}'.format(intr_req_count))
oe_interchange_required = ('OE Interchange Records Required: ', 
'{:,}'.format(oe_intr_req_count))
mpcc = ('MPCC Required: ', '{:,}'.format(valid_count))  # Every valid part 
requires a MPCC
attributes = ('Attributes Required: ', '{:,}'.format(valid_count))  # Every 
valid part requires attributes
image_required = ('Image Required: ', '{:,}'.format(part_img_req_count))
upc = ('UPC Requited: ', '{:,}'.format(upc_req_count))
warranties = ('Warranty Text/PDF Required: ', '{:,}'.format(valid_count))  # 
Require warranty text/pdf on all parts
unspsc = ('UNSPSC Code Required: ', '{:,}'.format(valid_count))  # Require 
UNSPSC Codes for all parts
msds = ('MSDS Required: ', '{:,}'.format(msds_req_count))

# Statements for Missing Counts
missing_applications = ('Missing Applications: ', 
'{:,}'.format(missing_app_count))
missing_interchange = ('Missing Interchange: ', 
'{:,}'.format(missing_intr_count))
missing_oe_interchange = ('Missing OE Interchange: ', 
'{:,}'.format(missing_oe_intr_count))
missing_mpcc = ('Missing MPCC: ', '{:,}'.format(missing_mpcc_count))
missing_attributes = ('Missing Attributes: ', 
'{:,}'.format(missing_attr_values_count))
missing_image = ('Missing Image: ', '{:,}'.format(missing_part_img_count))
missing_UPC = ('Missing UPC: ', '{:,}'.format(missing_upc_count))
missing_warranty_text = ('Missing Warranty Text: ', 
'{:,}'.format(missing_warr_text_count))
missing_warranty_pdf = ('Missing Warranty PDF: ', 
'{:,}'.format(missing_warr_pdf_count))
missing_unspsc = ('Missing UNSPSC Code: ', 
'{:,}'.format(missing_unspsc_count))
missing_msds = ('Missing MSDS: ', '{:,}'.format(missing_msds_count))

# CSV Output
report_card.append(valid_parts)
report_card.append(application_required)
report_card.append(interchange_required)
report_card.append(oe_interchange_required)
report_card.append(mpcc)
report_card.append(attributes)
report_card.append(image_required)
report_card.append(upc)
report_card.append(warranties)
report_card.append(unspsc)
report_card.append(msds)
report_card.append(missing_applications)
report_card.append(missing_interchange)
report_card.append(missing_oe_interchange)
report_card.append(missing_mpcc)
report_card.append(missing_attributes)
report_card.append(missing_image)
report_card.append(missing_UPC)
report_card.append(missing_warranty_text)
report_card.append(missing_warranty_pdf)
report_card.append(missing_unspsc)
report_card.append(missing_msds)

for row in header:
    print(row)

for x in report_card:
    print(x)



with open('Report_Card.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(header)
    writer.writerows(report_card)
```

CSV file:

```
Supplier Line:,,Gates Rubber - Denver (GAT),,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Summary:,,Parts HQ Abbr,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
ACCT No:,,40013586,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
RecCount:,,10221,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Applicable Date:,,"June 14, 2017 (Wednesday)",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
HQ Line,Part No,Part Class,Appl Req,Appl Count ,Intr Req,Intr Count ,OE Intr Req,Has OE Intr,Has Attr Editor, Has Attr Values,Part IMG Req,Has Part IMG,Has MPCC,Warr Req,Has Warr TXT,Has Warr PDF,MSDS Req,Has MSDS,UPC Req,Has UPC,Has UNSPSC,Attr Count ,AttrVal Count ,Valid Part
GAT,'27210',S,NO,0,YES,1,YES,NO,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,NO,NO,YES,YES,YES,30,13,YES
GAT,'27211',O,NO,0,YES,1,YES,NO,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,NO,NO,YES,YES,YES,30,14,YES
GAT,'27212',S,NO,0,YES,1,YES,NO,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,NO,NO,YES,YES,YES,30,13,YES
GAT,'27213',S,NO,0,YES,1,YES,NO,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,NO,NO,YES,YES,YES,30,13,YES
GAT,'27220',S,NO,0,YES,2,YES,NO,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,NO,NO,YES,YES,YES,35,20,YES
GAT,'27221',S,NO,0,YES,2,YES,NO,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,NO,NO,YES,YES,YES,35,20,YES
```

Comment: A. I know my botch it wrong, because the enumerate worked for the .csv import but now it doesn't recognize book as an iteratable.

Comment: It would help if you edited your question to include a small sample from the XLSX file.

Comment: If all else fails, save your xlsx file as CSV, and work with that.

Comment: This is for a work process for a large number of .xlsx files. Opening and saving each individually wouldn't be efficient.

Comment: @MartinEvans posted my whole code and a data sample

Comment: If the excel is a matrix you should definatevely have a look at **Pandas** http://pandas.pydata.org/ and specifically the read Excel function https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: thanks @AntonvBR, right now the gentleman mentoring me on Python wants me to struggle through it without Pandas and then I can learn Pandas lol

Answer (score 2):

Since it's an Excel Workbook object and not just a .CSV file, your book object is made up of sheets. So first you have to grab a sheet you want to work with, then you need to get the rows by calling sheet.get_rows()

The code below should work, I tested it locally.

```
import xlrd

book = xlrd.open_workbook('GAT_US_PartReview_2017-06-23.xlsx')

header = []
report_card = []

# Count Stmnts for Required Data
valid_count = 0
app_req_count = 0
intr_req_count = 0

# Count Stmts for Missing Data
missing_app_count = 0
missing_intr_count = 0
missing_oe_intr_count = 0

sheet = book.sheets()[0]
for row_num, row in enumerate(sheet.get_rows()):
    if row_num <= 4:
        #  print(row)  # Print out the header
        header.append([row[0], row[2]])

print(header)
```

Answer (score 1):

This script allows you to transform an excel data table to a list of dictionaries:

```
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('GAT_US_PartReview_2017-06-23.xlsx', on_demand = True)
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
first_row = [] # The row where we stock the name of the column
for col in range(worksheet.ncols):
    first_row.append( worksheet.cell_value(0,col) )
# transform the workbook to a list of dictionaries
data =[]
for row in range(1, worksheet.nrows):
    elm = {}
    for col in range(worksheet.ncols):
        elm[first_row[col]]=worksheet.cell_value(row,col)
    data.append(elm)
print data
```

You can also use [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html)

```
from pandas import *
xls = ExcelFile('GAT_US_PartReview_2017-06-23.xlsx')
df = xls.parse(xls.sheet_names[0])
print df.to_dict()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code for accessing the `xlrd` library needed a few fixes as follows:

```
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('GAT_US_PartReview_2017-06-23.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

header = []
report_card = []

# Count Stmnts for Required Data
valid_count = 0
app_req_count = 0
intr_req_count = 0
oe_intr_req_count = 0
part_img_req_count = 0
upc_req_count = 0
unspsc_req_count = 0
msds_req_count = 0

# Count Stmts for Missing Data
missing_app_count = 0
missing_intr_count = 0
missing_oe_intr_count = 0
missing_mpcc_count = 0
missing_attr_values_count = 0
missing_part_img_count = 0
missing_upc_count = 0
missing_warr_text_count = 0
missing_warr_pdf_count = 0
missing_unspsc_count = 0
missing_msds_count = 0

for row_num in range(worksheet.nrows):
    row = worksheet.row_values(row_num)

    if row_num <= 4:
        #  print(row)  # Print out the header
        header.append([row[0], row[2]])
    else:
        hq_line, part_no, part_class, appl_req, appl_count, intr_req, \
        intr_count, oe_intr_req, has_oe_intr, has_attr_editor, \
        has_attr_values, part_img_req, has_part_img, has_mpcc, warr_req, \
        has_warr_txt, has_warr_pdf, msds_req, has_msds, upc_req, has_upc, \
        has_unspsc, attr_count, attrval_count, valid_part = row

        if valid_part == 'YES':
            valid_count += 1

            # Required Parts Count
            if appl_req == 'YES':
                app_req_count += 1
            if intr_req == 'YES':
                intr_req_count += 1
            if oe_intr_req == 'YES':
                oe_intr_req_count += 1
            if part_img_req == 'YES':
                part_img_req_count += 1
            if upc_req == 'YES':
                upc_req_count += 1
            if msds_req == 'YES':
                msds_req_count += 1

            # Missing Data Counts
            if appl_req == 'YES' and appl_count == '0':
                missing_app_count += 1
            if intr_req == 'YES' and intr_count == '0':
                missing_intr_count += 1
            if oe_intr_req == 'YES' and has_oe_intr == '0':
                 missing_oe_intr_count += 1
            if has_mpcc == 'NO':
                 missing_mpcc_count += 1
            if has_attr_values == 'NO':
                missing_attr_values_count += 1
            if has_part_img == 'NO':
                missing_part_img_count += 1
            if upc_req == 'YES' and has_upc == '0':
                missing_upc_count += 1
            if warr_req == 'YES' and has_warr_txt == 'NO':
                missing_warr_text_count += 1
            if warr_req == 'YES' and has_warr_pdf == 'NO':
                missing_warr_pdf_count += 1
            if has_unspsc == 'NO':
                missing_unspsc_count += 1
            if msds_req == 'YES' and has_msds == 'NO':
                missing_msds_count += 1

# Statements for Required Counts
valid_parts = ('Number of Valid Parts: ', '{:,}'.format(valid_count))
application_required = ('Application Records Required: ', '{:,}'.format(app_req_count))
interchange_required = ('Interchange Records Required: ', '{:,}'.format(intr_req_count))
oe_interchange_required = ('OE Interchange Records Required: ', '{:,}'.format(oe_intr_req_count))
mpcc = ('MPCC Required: ', '{:,}'.format(valid_count))  # Every valid part requires a MPCC
attributes = ('Attributes Required: ', '{:,}'.format(valid_count))  # Every valid part requires attributes
image_required = ('Image Required: ', '{:,}'.format(part_img_req_count))
upc = ('UPC Requited: ', '{:,}'.format(upc_req_count))
warranties = ('Warranty Text/PDF Required: ', '{:,}'.format(valid_count))  # Require warranty text/pdf on all parts
unspsc = ('UNSPSC Code Required: ', '{:,}'.format(valid_count))  # Require UNSPSC Codes for all parts
msds = ('MSDS Required: ', '{:,}'.format(msds_req_count))

# Statements for Missing Counts
missing_applications = ('Missing Applications: ', '{:,}'.format(missing_app_count))
missing_interchange = ('Missing Interchange: ', '{:,}'.format(missing_intr_count))
missing_oe_interchange = ('Missing OE Interchange: ', '{:,}'.format(missing_oe_intr_count))
missing_mpcc = ('Missing MPCC: ', '{:,}'.format(missing_mpcc_count))
missing_attributes = ('Missing Attributes: ', '{:,}'.format(missing_attr_values_count))
missing_image = ('Missing Image: ', '{:,}'.format(missing_part_img_count))
missing_UPC = ('Missing UPC: ', '{:,}'.format(missing_upc_count))
missing_warranty_text = ('Missing Warranty Text: ', '{:,}'.format(missing_warr_text_count))
missing_warranty_pdf = ('Missing Warranty PDF: ', '{:,}'.format(missing_warr_pdf_count))
missing_unspsc = ('Missing UNSPSC Code: ', '{:,}'.format(missing_unspsc_count))
missing_msds = ('Missing MSDS: ', '{:,}'.format(missing_msds_count))

# CSV Output
report_card.append(valid_parts)
report_card.append(application_required)
report_card.append(interchange_required)
report_card.append(oe_interchange_required)
report_card.append(mpcc)
report_card.append(attributes)
report_card.append(image_required)
report_card.append(upc)
report_card.append(warranties)
report_card.append(unspsc)
report_card.append(msds)
report_card.append(missing_applications)
report_card.append(missing_interchange)
report_card.append(missing_oe_interchange)
report_card.append(missing_mpcc)
report_card.append(missing_attributes)
report_card.append(missing_image)
report_card.append(missing_UPC)
report_card.append(missing_warranty_text)
report_card.append(missing_warranty_pdf)
report_card.append(missing_unspsc)
report_card.append(missing_msds)

for row in header:
    print(row)

for x in report_card:
    print(x)

with open('Report_Card.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(header)
    writer.writerows(report_card)
```

For the data you have provided, this gives you a `Report_Card.csv` file as follows:

```
Supplier Line:  Gates Rubber - Denver (GAT)
Summary:    Parts HQ Abbr
ACCT No:    40013586
RecCount:   10221
Applicable Date:    June 14, 2017 (Wednesday)
Number of Valid Parts:  6
Application Records Required:   0
Interchange Records Required:   6
OE Interchange Records Required:    6
MPCC Required:  6
Attributes Required:    6
Image Required:     6
UPC Requited:   6
Warranty Text/PDF Required:     6
UNSPSC Code Required:   6
MSDS Required:  0
Missing Applications:   0
Missing Interchange:    0
Missing OE Interchange:     0
Missing MPCC:   0
Missing Attributes:     0
Missing Image:  0
Missing UPC:    0
Missing Warranty Text:  0
Missing Warranty PDF:   0
Missing UNSPSC Code:    0
Missing MSDS:   0
```

Your code could certainly do with a rethink. Rather than having so many variables, i.e. one per column, think about using something like a Python [`Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=counter#collections.Counter) which works like a dictionary. Working with lists or dictionaries would make your code much simpler.